# I am getting ArrayOutOfBoundException on a byte[] array? And I don't know why

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert a file to byte array and send through socket to my server written in python.
But when I try convert the file to byte I get this error -

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1048576; regionStart=1048576; regionLength=1048576
```

Code that runs when I press the upload button -

```
Button upload = binding.button2;
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //I have stored the path of the file which is a string in a arraylist 
                //"files" is an obj of that ArrayList
                System.out.println("Inside OnClick" + files.size()); 
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                        Path path = Paths.get(files.get(i));
                        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(files.get(i)));
                        int size = (int)Files.size(path);
                        int iter = size/(1024 * 1024) + 1;
                        System.out.println(size + "  " + iter);
                        Thread send = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(1048576); // 1048576 = 1MB
                                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(SocketHandler.getSocket().getOutputStream());
                                        out.write("upl sample.mkv".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                                        Thread.sleep(200);
                                        out.write(String.valueOf(size).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                                        Thread.sleep(200);
                                        int off = 0;
                                        for(int j = 0;j < iter;j++){
                                            if(j == iter - 1){
                                                off += in.read(data.array(),off,size - off);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                // This where I get the error 
                                                //And the error is always on the second iteration
                                                off += in.read(data.array(), off, 1048576); 
                                            }
                                            data.clear();
                                        }
                                        System.out.println(off);

                                    }catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        send.start();
                        send.join();
                  }
                }catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is what was printed in logs -

```
D/ViewRootImpl@1d9e105[MainActivity2]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/System.out: Inside OnClick1
I/System.out: 259728246  248
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
    Process: com.iot.ftpserver, PID: 30412
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1048576; regionStart=1048576; regionLength=1048576
        at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:135)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:307)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:152)
        at com.iot.ftpserver.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment$1$1.run(GalleryFragment.java:104)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30412 SIG: 9
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would guess that the way you intend to "iterate" here doesn't work with how that Buffer class works. Most likely you are sending numbers to it that are just way too large.

Comment: I think the issue is when you increment the off, then it causes the next next in.read to start writing data into the end of the data array where there are no more indexes to write into. The doc says: off - the start offset in the destination array b, so if you just leave off at 0 it should be fine.

Comment: @Nicolas125841 Your answer worked like charm thanks for taking me out of this horrifying situation

Comment: @WhiteVulpes Glad it worked!